# How to generate a random string by giving input string from excel in java

Tags: java

I have some keyword as input and I want to generate a string using permutations and combination of that keywords.I am having these keywords Jacket,leather,red,,dress,wool,blue,coat,cotton,pink.I want output string combination of these. Eg. blue leather jacket
This may be a duplicate question but I have gone through

1) How to generate a random String in Java

2) How to generate a random string

3) How to generate a random string of 20 characters

these questions but I did not get satisfying answer

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution:

1. put all your strings into a list
2. [shuffle](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_shuffle.htm) that list
3. pick the first *n* entries of that list

Like:

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList("Jacket" ,"leather" ...);
Collections.shuffle(words);
for (int i=0;i< whatever; i++) {
  System.out.println("one random word:" + words.get(i));
}
```

Other options: you keep a static list of words (meaning: you don't modify that list); and then you simply draw random numbers between 0 and list.size() - meaning: you pick random indexes and use those to pick the corresponding words from your list.